# Why nuxt3 fails to reach the api?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

We are developing an application with nuxt3 rc-6 and recently we noticed a recurring behavior on api calls in ssr.
Let's consider the following proxy:

```
/server/api/messages/getMessages.post.ts
```

```js
import { WS } from "~~/data";
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig();
  const body = await useBody(event);
  console.log(`${config.API_BASE_URL}${WS.buzz.answers}/${body.companyId}`);
  try {
    const response  = await $fetch(
      `${config.API_BASE_URL}${WS.buzz.answers}/${body.companyId}`,
      {
        method:"POST",
        body
      });
      return response
  } catch (e) {
    return {
      data: [],
    };
  }
});
```

It does call the api in the background but randomly 1 out of 3 times it catches an error so this call sends us back the data: []

What do you think is the problem?

Comment: What is the cause of error? What is value of `e` when error occurs?

Comment: Can you inspect the HTTP call that you are sending/receiving on the backend?